# Dropbox API stripping MP3 tags

Tags: php, upload, mp3, dropbox-api

I am synchronizing a Centos directory of MP3's with a Dropbox shared folder. When I copy MP3 files into the folder in Windows all is well.  When I upload from Centos using a PHP script and the REST interface the files arrive, but they're a larger size and are missing the tags. I can still play the files so it's not simple file corruption.  I'm opening the file in binary mode in the PHP script.  Here's the relevant code:

```
    $path = $this->dropboxPath($root, $subDir, $fileName);
    $uri = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/auto/$path";

    $lclPath = storage_path() . "/$root/$subDir/$fileName";

    $fd = fopen($lclPath, 'rb');

    $this->putDropbox($uri, [
        'overwrite' => 'true'
        ], $fd
    );

private function putDropbox($uri, $parms, $fd) {
    $uri = $uri . "?" . http_build_query($parms);
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $req = $client->createRequest('PUT', $uri, [
        'exceptions' => true,
        'body' => [
            'file_filed' => $fd
        ]
    ]);

    $req->setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $this->token);

    try {
        $resp = $client->send($req);
        return $resp;
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e->getRequest());

        if($e->hasResponse()) {
            Log::error($e->getResponse());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the docs for Guzzle ( http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#request-options ), it looks like you're passing the file content using the array POST style:        `'body' => [
            'file_filed' => $fd
        ]`. Try `'body' => $fd` instead.

Comment: That seems to have done it, thanks!  I don't really understand why the first method would strip tags, but all's well that ends well.